# Top Bar and Dock Icons very large

Tags: release-juno, display, plank, icons

I have a problem, my elementary OS Juno, it has the top bar and the very large dock icons. The screen resolution  has the standard size of my notebook. See my pictures:

[image]

But my resolution have **1366 x 768**:

[image]

Can someone help me ? Before everything was normal, I turned on the computer and it appeared like this today.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it seems you're using a different icon theme. That should be the culprit.
Change the icon back to Elementary and that should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that is a theme problem. Did you changed it? Try beginning a new session as guest